# Strange crash when accessing Core Data from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, core-data, null, appdelegate

In my app I try to access Core Data right at the end of application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions using the code below. This is usually no problem throughout the app (I use the same code multiple times elsewhere) but at this point it crash as you can see below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIView *splashScreen = [self splashScreen];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:splashScreen];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window setRootViewController:[[UIViewController alloc]init]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self configureRestKit];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        ... do stuff ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        ... more stuff (remove splash screen etc.) ...

HERE I CALL THE CODE! --->  [self uploadPossibleDrives];

        }



        });

    });

    return YES;
}
```

This is the code I call from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (uploadPossibleDrives):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [kDelegate managedObjectContext];
if (!managedObjectContext) return;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"driveID" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil)
{
    [kDelegate showAlert:kErrorTitle withMessage:kNoContextMessage andButton:kDismissButton];
}
else
{
    while (history = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    if (![controller containsObject:history.car])
            {

                NSMutableDictionary *driveDataByCar = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [driveDataByCar setObject:history.car forKey:@"car"];
CRASH! ----->   [driveDataByCar setObject:history.energy forKey:@"energy"];
                [driveDataByCar setObject:history.energy_onlyDrive forKey:@"energy_only_drive"];
                [driveDataByCar setObject:history.cw forKey:@"cw"];
                [driveDataByCar setObject:history.weight forKey:@"weight"];
                [driveDataByCar setObject:history.area forKey:@"area"];
                [driveDataByCar setObject:history.maxPower forKey:@"maxPower"];
                [carDataToUpload addObject:driveDataByCar];

                [controller addObject:history.car];
                }

            }

            ...

}
```

Here is the crash report:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: energy)
0 CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess + 130
2 CoreFoundation -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 818
3 App UploadDriveData.m line 140 -[UploadDriveData uploadDrivingData]
4 App AppDelegate.m line 302 __32-[AppDelegate uploadDrivingData]_block_invoke250
5 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread + 8

Crashed: Thread
SIGABRT ABORT at 0x3ba541f0
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __pthread_kill + 8
9 CoreFoundation -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 818
10 App UploadDriveData.m line 140 -[UploadDriveData uploadDrivingData]
11 App AppDelegate.m line 302 __32-[AppDelegate uploadDrivingData]_block_invoke250
12 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_wqthread + 298`
```

I really dont know why the app gets a nil for 'energy'.
Anybody else have an idea why this happens in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and nowhere else in the app?
Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: for debug add code with log and breakpoint to case where `history.energy == nil` and from this point try to understand how this happens

Comment: How is the property `energy` declared?

Comment: Could you `NSLog` `history`?

Comment: You're trying to insert a nil, because you fetched an object that has no value for `energy`. You need to figure out how and why you created that object, and you need to check for nil before trying to insert the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that at another point in my app a mutable array was sometimes getting pre released which contained the values of energy and energy_onlyDrive. So those were actually set to nil.
Thanks everybody for your help!